# XML e4x and creating arrays in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a http service producing the following resutls  svcSessionCreate.lastResult.children())

I'm looking for a way to use those results in my application.  Currently the only way I know how to do it is using a datagrid - and I don't want to do that this time.  I want to be able to drill down to a particular node in the xml.

How do I create a variable that I can use.  I was trying this but it's not working.

```
private var myXMLListCollection:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
        myXMLListCollection.source ="{XMLList(svcSessionCreate.lastResult.children())}";
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tree control. Here's an example to get you started.
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/15/expanding-nodes-in-a-flex-tree-control-using-the-openitems-property/